# sqlite db2 error for symbian

Tags: c++, sqlite, symbian

i am getting error for statement

```
TInt err1 =stmt.Prepare(db,_L("INSERT INTO MyContacts(ServerContactID,UserName,FirstName,LastName,Country,IsBlocked,RequestStatus,MarkForDeletion) VALUES(:ServerContactID,:UserName,:FirstName,:LastName,:Country,:IsBlocked,:RequestStatus,:MarkForDeletion)"));
```

for this statements

if i print err1

i am getting 311 error

Answer (score 1):

-311 error from `sqldb.h`:

```
/**
An SQL database-specific error type return code from a call to the SQL API.

It indicates a general SQL error or a missing database.

@see RSqlStatement
@see ESqlDbError
@see TSqlRetCodeClass

@publishedAll
@prototype
*/
const TInt KSqlErrGeneral       = -311;
```

So the obvious first questions are:

- Is the `RSqlDatabase db` properly connected?
- Does the database have a table called `MyContacts`?

It is also a good habit to always end your SQL statements with a semicolon `;` even though they are not always strictly necessary. (Don't have the tools here to test whether it is required in this case.)